# Extending terminal colors to the end of line

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bash script which generates a motd. The problem is depending on some terminal settings which I am not sure about the color will extend to the end of the line. Othertimes it doesn't:

e.g.

[image: square]

v.s.

[image: jagged]

IIRC one is just the normal gnome-terminal and the other is my tmux term. So my question is how can I get this to extend to 80 character (or really to the terminal width). Of course I can pad to 80 chars but that really doesn't solve the problem.

Here is a snip of my code which generates the motd:

```
TC_RESET="^[[0m"                                                                
TC_SKY="^[[0;37;44m"                                                            
TC_GRD="^[[0;30;42m"                                                            
TC_TEXT="^[[38;5;203m"   

echo -n "${TC_SKY}                                                                              

... lots of printing..." 
echo -e "\n                           Welcome to Mokon's Linux!                           \n"

echo -n "${TC_GRD}"                                                             
nodeinfo # Just prints the info seen below...                                                                       
echo ${TC_RESET}
```

How can I programmatically from bash change the terminal settings or something change the color to the end of the line?

Comment: You could simply flush your screen before typing anything: `echo $'\e[33;44;1m\e[H\e[J'` at top of your script.

Comment: @F.Hauri Thanks. How do I turn the screen back to normal now after that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe use the [Escape sequence to clear-to-EOL](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html)

For some reason (on my MacOS terminal!) I only needed specify this sequence and then it worked for all the lines but for completeness I list it for all

```
TC_RESET=$'\x1B[0m'
TC_SKY=$'\x1B[0;37;44m'
TC_GRD=$'\x1B[0;30;42m'
TC_TEXT=$'\x1B[38;5;203m'
CLREOL=$'\x1B[K'

echo -n "${TC_SKY}${CLREOL}"
echo -e "\n           ABC${CLREOL}\n"
echo -e "\n              DEFG${CLREOL}\n"

echo -n "${TC_GRD}"
echo -e "\n           ABC${CLREOL}\n"
echo -e "\n              DEFG${CLREOL}\n"
echo ${TC_RESET}
```

Comment: Thank You! And Thanks to the others who also tried but this solutions works the way I was hoping. I made a few alterations. Basically I append to a temp file and then use send to replace all the newlines with a newline and that char. If I don't put that escape sequence on each line I only get it on the lines with it... I'll add that to your answer for others...

Comment: @DavidMokonBond  My sample was based on experimentation on my Mac, obviously you are using a wider set of terminals.  So I updated my answer - can you validate?

Comment: I don't use `tmux`, what is the reported terminal type (`${TERM}`) and is the behaviour similar on `screen`?

Comment: Yes, its very similar to screen. For now I just sent it through sed and padded it to 80 chars which works enough for me. Here is the term:

i:echo ${TERM}
screen-256color

After googling a bit I think it might be due to tmux not supporting all the same term features such as the eol line one you are using but I'm not really sure

Comment: I know it functions like screen, I was asking if your app behaves in screen as it does in tmux.  Padding will of course work, but can get tricky as you may have some invisible characters.  if i had to pad I would consider using printf in bash (`printf ">>%-80s<<\n"  "hello"`)

Comment: The clear-to-EOL works perfectly on OS X/macOS (tested most recently on OS X 10.11.6) in the standard Terminal. Thanks for this great tip!

Comment: looks like recent tmux (~2.4) [fixes this](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/4179b4242411f41a22d9743b4eff3b19ef69b3e8)

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal is, but the color staying to the end of the line doesn't take effect until after the first newline. So it seems that an extra line has to get used up. Wonder if this can be avoided. For example `echo "^[K^[[44;33m11111\naaaaa\nbbbbb^[[m"` the `11111` doesn't get the proper treatment

Answer (score 3):

#### Padding filter

Unfortunely, you **have to** pad each line with exact number of spaces for changing the color of the whole line's background.

As you're speaking about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), my solution will use *bashisms* (Won't work under other shell, or older version of bash).

- syntax `printf -v VAR FORM ARGS` assign to varianble `VAR` then result of `sprintf FORM ARGS`. That's bashism, under other kind of shell, you have to replace this line by `TC_SPC=$(printf "%${COLUMNS}s" '')`

You may try this:

```
... lots of printing..." 
echo -e "\n                           Welcome to Mokon's Linux!                           \n"

echo -n "${TC_GRD}"

printf -v TC_SPC "%${COLUMNS}s" ''

nodeinfo |
    sed "s/$/$TC_SPC/;s/^\\(.\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1/" # Just prints the info seen below...

echo ${TC_RESET}
```

[image]
Maybe you have to ensure that `$COLUMNS` is correctly setted:

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
```

As you could see, only the result of command filtered by `sed` is fully colored.

you may

- use same filter many times:

  ```
  cmd1 | sed '...'
  cmd2 | sed '...'
  ```
- or group your commands to use only one filter:

  ```
  ( cmd1 ; cmd 2 ) | sed '...'
  ```

But there is an issue in case you try to filter ouptut that contain *formatting escapes*:

```
(
    echo $'\e[33;44;1mYellow text on blue background';
    seq 1 6;
    echo $'\e[0m'
) | sed "
  s/$/$TC_SPC/;
  s/^\\(.\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1/"
```

[image: unterminated sample]

Il the lines you have to pad to contain *escapes*, you have to isolate thems:

```
(
    echo $'\e[33;44;1mYellow text on blue background';
    seq 1 6;
    echo $'\e[0m'
) | sed "
  s/\$/$TC_SPC/;
  s/^\\(\\(\\o33\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]\\)*\\)\\([^\o033]\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1\\3/
"
```

[image]

And finally to be able to fill terminate very long lines:

```
(
    echo $'\e[33;44;1mYellow text on blue background';
    seq 1 6;
    echo "This is a very very long long looooooooooong line that contain\
       more characters than the line could hold...";
    echo $'\e[0m';
) | sed "            
  s/\$/$TC_SPC/;
  s/^\\(\\(\\o33\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]\\)*\\)\\(\\([^\o033]\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\)*\\) */\\1\\3/"
```

Nota: This only work if formating escapes are located at begin of line.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
echo -e '\E[33;44m'"yellow text on blue background"; tput sgr0
```