# Bash prompt with background color extending to end of line

Tags: bash, sed, prompt

It's bash-prompt-fiddling-time for me (had to happen one day...).

I'm trying to get a 2-line prompt:

- 1st line with location info, and background color to the end of line
- 2nd line with time and exit code of previous command

I'm almost there, but I can't crack the "background color to the end of line" part. Not quite.

Putting together bits of info from several sources, and most importantly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715103/bash-prompt-with-last-exit-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915208/extending-terminal-colors-to-the-end-of-line), I get [this result (terminal screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnNwu.png).

As you can see, something's wrong with the COLUMNS calculations:

- it does not reach the end of line
- it depends on the text length on the 1st line
- it gets worse when reaching the bottom of the terminal; it does reach the end of line then; the wrong line...
- another weird thing: the tiny [ ] which are bracketing the 2nd prompt line; and those ONLY APPEAR AFTER A COMMAND IS ENTERED

This is my bashrc code:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
__prompt_command()
{
    local EXIT="$?" 

    local Red='\[\033[1;38;5;9m\]'
    local Green='\[\033[1;38;5;10m\]'
    local Gray='\[\033[0;38;5;248m\]'
    local BgBlue='\[\033[48;5;253;1;38;5;12m\]'
    local BgPurple='\[\033[48;5;253;1;38;5;93m\]'
    local None='\[\e[0m\]'

    PS1="${BgPurple}\u@\h:${BgBlue}\$PWD"

    printf -v TC_SPC "%${COLUMNS}s" ''

    COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
    PS1=`echo $PS1 | sed "s/$/$TC_SPC/; s/^\\(.\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1/"`

    PS1+="\n${Gray}\D{%F %T}"

    if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
        PS1+=" ${Red} O_o ${None}"      # Add red if exit code non 0
    else
        PS1+="${Green} ^_^ ${None}"
    fi
}
```

I tried more hacking but no success.

Oh, there another more sophisticated version of the sed bit, which I also tried:

```
    PS1=`echo $PS1 | sed "s/$/$TC_SPC/; s/^\\(\\(\\o33\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]\\)*\\)\\([^\o033]\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1\\3/"`
```

[Different result (terminal screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFlag.png) but still not OK.

At this point I'm taking any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
printf -v TC_SPC "%${COLUMNS}s" ''

COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
PS1=`echo $PS1 | sed "s/$/$TC_SPC/; s/^\\(.\\{${COLUMNS}\\}\\) */\\1/"`
```

Use:

```
PS1+=$'\033[K' #erase to end of line
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, works perfect and so simple... I had to add this after both lines, the second one was needed to fix the problem when reaching the bottom of the terminal. Out of curiosity what's the '$' intended for in your suggestion ? I tried with and without it, and it seems to achieve the same.

Comment: In bash, `$'STRING'` is like a single-quoted string, but gives special meaning to backslash-escaped sequences. In this case, `\nnn` is replaced with "the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)". Octal 033 is the escape character. See `man bash` and search for `$'` for the full list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working solution, thanks to Eric's "erase to end of line" hint.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command # Func to gen PS1 after CMDs
__prompt_command()
{
  local EXIT="$?"             # This needs to be first (retrieves last commmand exit code)

  local Red='\[\033[1;38;5;9m\]'
  local Green='\[\033[1;38;5;10m\]'
  local Gray='\[\033[0;38;5;248m\]'
  local BgBlue='\[\033[48;5;253;1;38;5;12m\]'
  local BgPurple='\[\033[48;5;253;1;38;5;93m\]'
  local None='\[\e[0m\]'

  PS1="${BgPurple}\u@\h:${BgBlue}\$PWD"
  PS1+="\033[K"             # erase to end of 1st line (background color stays)

  PS1+="\n${Gray}\D{%F %T}\a"

  if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
    PS1+="${Red} O_o ${None}"   # Add red if exit code non 0
  else
    PS1+="${Green} ^_^ ${None}"
  fi
  PS1+="\033[K"             # erase to end of 2nd line (no more background color)
}
```

And [here is the result (terminal screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K99CC.png). One more happy prompt owner...